# UITextView issue in iOS 8 : text view not scroll when entering text

Tags: scroll, keyboard, uitextview, ios8

I am facing issue in iOS 8 in prior version is working perfect.

My text view is around 4 line when I am entering text more then 4 line text view automaticaly scroll up but in this case not scroll in iOS8.

Here is my code.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

    NSString *updatedString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    textView.text = updatedString;
    return NO;


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{

    NSString *updatedString = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
    //textView.text = updatedString;
    [textView replaceRange:textView.selectedTextRange withText:text];
    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit the text of a UITextView, you need to update it's textStorage field:

```
[_textView.textStorage beginEditing];

NSRange replace = NSMakeRange(10, 2); //enter your editing range
[_textView.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:replace withString:@"ha ha$ "];

//if you want to edit the attributes
NSRange attributeRange = NSMakeRange(10, 5); //enter your editing attribute range
[_textView.textStorage addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:attributeRange];

[_textView.textStorage endEditing];
```

Good luck